# Loading for a certain div, with indicator & click on some button when its done

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, load, loading

I have a page that loads pretty fast instead of the image gallery in it. I prefer not to have loading for the entire page , but have a loading "with loading indicator" for a certain div.
The gallery will load eventually, but, is there a way to:

1. have a loading for it's **certain div**( like #gallery, or .gallery)
2. and show **a loading gif or such** at the *center* of this div, that *disappears* automatically when loading is done?
3. After it loads, some certain button with a certain class or id (like #button or .button) clicks automatically?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i think Ajax will help you accomplish this.

Comment: yes, all of that is possible, you just need to use iFrames and jQuery

Comment: You can see this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/spirit-dev/GifLoader)

Comment: No, don't use iframes. Use AJAX. Iframes are a last resort, never a solution.

Comment: @AminJafari I agree with Rory.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I do too! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="myDiv">
<img src="loading gif image url">
</div>
<script>
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url to the page where the contnt is",
            data: 'parameters if any' ,
            success: function(result){
                $("#myDiv").html(result);
                $( "#buttonId" ).trigger( "click" );//triggering click on your dfesired button
            });
</script>
```

Comment: Dear Sarath--Thank you for this. It has url:... which is the URL to the page where content is. Can we say something like "this page" and no URL? Thanks again.

Comment: i didnt understand what you mean. Anyway if you need to load a content in the same page u need not ajax call. Ajax  is for calling remote files. If ur file is in the same page u just need to load the div directly as $("#myDiv").html("Your contnt to be loaded");